# How to download a .jar file from a URL

Tags: java, http, urlconnection, guvnor

I have to download a .jar file from a remote kie maven repository which requires authentication using my java code.
The code is as follows.

```
String url = "http://localhost:18080/kiewb/maven2/group/artifact/version/file.jar";
        UrlResource urlResource = (UrlResource) resources.newUrlResource(url);
        urlResource.setUsername("username"); 
        urlResource.setPassword("password");

        urlResource.setBasicAuthentication("enabled");

    InputStream is = urlResource.getInputStream();
```

But, its throwing

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL:http://localhost:18080/kiewb/maven2/group/artifact/version/file.jar
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1839)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1440)
    at url.main(url.java:47)
```

And in the server in which the maven repo is, I am getting the following error.
My server is Wildfly10.

```
ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-58) UT005023: Exception handling request to /kiewb/maven2/group/artifact/version/file.jar: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
        at org.uberfire.ext.security.server.BasicAuthSecurityFilter.authenticate(BasicAuthSecurityFilter.java:112)
        at org.uberfire.ext.security.server.BasicAuthSecurityFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthSecurityFilter.java:69)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at org.uberfire.ext.security.server.SecureHeadersFilter.doFilter(SecureHeadersFilter.java:69)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at org.uberfire.ext.security.server.SecurityIntegrationFilter.doFilter(SecurityIntegrationFilter.java:57)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:53)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:59)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
        at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
        at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
        at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
        at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
        at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
        at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
        at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:805)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

And the same jar  I am able to download it by directly hitting the URL in the browser.

Comment: response code is 500. that means there is an error in server side. check server logs, solve that issue first.

Comment: HTTP response code `500` is "Internal Server Error". So you most probably have a problem with the server. Try downloading the file with `curl` or something from command line.

Comment: While downloading from browser is it asking for any authentications?

Comment: are you using an empty password? there was a similar issue reported here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jbpm-development/28r-V0M63Ww

Comment: While downloading in browser its not asking any authentication.

Comment: I am passing the actual password.
Without username and password, its returning 401.After giving the authentication its 500.

Comment: Error is coming from uberfire jar. If you have the source, you can debug and see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try another way to download. Note that it should be Java 8

```
public void downloadFile(String fromUrl, String localFileName) throws IOException {
    File localFile = new File(localFileName);
    if (localFile.exists()) {
        localFile.delete();
    }
    localFile.createNewFile();
    URL url = new URL(fromUrl);
    OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(localFileName));
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    String encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(("username"+":"+"password").getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));  //Java 8
    conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic "+ encoded);
    InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

    int numRead;
    while ((numRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, numRead);
    }
    if (in != null) {
        in.close();
    }
    if (out != null) {
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I get the latest updated file file from the same directory?

Comment: What you mean " latest updated file file from the same directory"?

Comment: Like If I have 3 files in one directory, I want to download the last updated file, Means file not based on the name, but in the time modified.

Comment: I think it depends on your server. Your server should have a API to get the latest file URL, then from the latest file URL, you can download the latest file.
Or you can provide a API in server to download latest file. Something like http://host:port/download-latest-file. And on the server, you can find the latest file and give it to client

Answer (score 0):

Simply rename the newest file to file name that is in your application and then download it. The example above is very good for launchers, because it delete the old file.